# Given an Array of Images, how do I style the images so that it looks like this ? ( React )

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

http://hbnam.tumblr.com/

Go this website and you will see the images in a grid. The grid appears completely random, but upon further examination, we see that the page is autopagerized and the images come in blocks of 15 each. But each block is still completely different.

I have an array of images and I want to do something like

```
array.map( ( element, index) => (
  <div **STYLES**>
    <img key={index} src={element} />
  </div>
)
```

but with proper styling.

Any clue on how to do the styling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are only interested in the styling aspect, just inspect the elements. You'll see that all they are doing to achieve that "grid" like layout is set the height of each image and then they are all centered by the `<body>` tag using `text-align: center`.

The thing is that in your example code, your using a `<div>` which defaults to `display: block`. On that tumblr page, each image is wrapped in an `<a>` tag which defaults to `display: inline`, so if you wanted to continue using the `<div>` to wrap each image, you'd need to set the `style` prop as such: `style={{display: 'inline'}}` and set `text-align: center` on the parent element wrapping the array of divs/images.

I hope this helps you, let me know if it did not.

```
const Images = ({images}) => {
  const wrapperStyle = {
    textAlign: 'center'
  };
  const imageStyle = {
    display: 'inline'
  };

  return (
    <div style={wrapperStyle}>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <div style={imageStyle}>
          <img key={index} src={image} height="300" />
        </div>
      ));}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the images are arranged in rows, each row having "randomly" 1,2 or 3 images. And you have mentioned, images are obtained 15 at a time.
How about if you show 15 images, with no. of images in each row set to be something like follows (the numbers add up to 15).

2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1

Center the images and set all images to same height, width auto based on aspect ratio, which adds to the perceived randomness.

I guess you can figure out the code, but let me know if I can help.